# REST API JavaScript - How to retrieve a file from a nested folder in document library by file ID?

Tags: javascript, document-library, rest, file

I use an ajax call on:

```
http://<:site>/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(<:DOCUMENT_LIBRARY_NAME>)/Files
```

But I need something like:

```
http://<:site>/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(<:DOCUMENT_LIBRARY_NAME>/<:FOLDER_NAME>)/Files?id eq <:id>
```

I just need to retrieve a specific file (by it's id) from nested folder in content library.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('MyDocuments')/RootFolder/Folders('D1')/Folders('D2')/Files?$expand=ListItemAllFields
```

Returns files properties along with associated list item properties.